# What does SmartClient have to do with SmartGwt?

Tags: smartgwt, smartclient

I'm attempting to get a simple SmartGWT app running(I have the GWT toolkit and SDK installed in Eclipse). I've tried simple tutorials such as this one...

http://hilloldebnath.byethost3.com/2009/08/29/smartgwt-a-getting-started-guide/

When I run-as(Web Application) and I am provided with a link I double click the link. The only thing to show up is the text in the html(no SmartGwt components are shown). I keep seeing references(in documentation) to SmartClient but I am not sure of what it does. Do I need SmartClient to develop with SmartGwt components or is something else happening?

I will also provide the console output. There are some errors in the console also and I'm not quite sure what they mean...

```
 [WARN] Server class 'org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.ELContextCleaner' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/dev/tools/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.6.0/gwt-2.6.0/gwt-dev.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/C:/dev/tools/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.6.0/gwt-2.6.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
Linking modules
   Bootstrap link for command-line module 'com.test.smartgwt.TestSmartGwt'
      Linking module 'testsmartgwt'
         Invoking Linker Cross-Site-Iframe
            [ERROR] The Cross-Site-Iframe linker does not support <script> tags in the gwt.xml files, but the gwt.xml file (or the gwt.xml files which it includes) contains the following script tags: 
sc/modules/ISC_Core.js
sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js
sc/modules/ISC_Containers.js
sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js
sc/modules/ISC_Forms.js
sc/modules/ISC_RichTextEditor.js
sc/modules/ISC_Calendar.js
sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js
sc/skins/Enterprise/load_skin.js
In order for your application to run correctly, you will need to include these tags in your host page directly. In order to avoid this error, you will need to remove the script tags from the gwt.xml file, or add this property to the gwt.xml file: <set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE'/>
[ERROR] shell failed in doSlowStartup method
[WARN] 404 - GET /testsmartgwt/testsmartgwt.nocache.js () 1401 bytes
   Request headers
      Host: 
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
      Accept: */*
      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
      Referer: http://******8888/TestSmartGwt.html?gwt.codesvr=******9997
      Connection: keep-alive
   Response headers
      Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
      Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
      Content-Length: 1401
[WARN] 404 - GET /testsmartgwt/testsmartgwt.nocache.js (****) 1401 bytes
   Request headers
      Host: localhost
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
      Accept: */*
      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
      Referer: http://******8888/TestSmartGwt.html?gwt.codesvr=******:9997
      Connection: keep-alive
   Response headers
      Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
      Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
      Content-Length: 1401
```

Comment: You should ask this on forums.smartclient.com

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after commenting this on the .gwt.xml file

```
<!--<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>-->
```

I'm using gwt 2.6 and smartgwt 4

Answer (score 0):

Try it again after removing

```
<script> var isomorphicDir = "testsmartgwt/sc/"; </script>
```

from your host HTML file.

---

If still there is any issue then please let me know about the version of SMARTGWT and GWT.